# Why is "string".to_i = 0 but "9".to_i =9

Tags: ruby

Hello I was wondering why this was the case and how to_i is defined.

simple question why does

```
"string".to_i
=> 0?


"9".to_i
=> 9
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation for `to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i), "if there is not a valid a number at the start of `str`, 0 is returned".

Comment: Might be worth noting that `nil.to_i` is `0` so `'pancakes'.to_i.nil?` would be sort of inconsistent. Having `nil.to_i == 0` is all kinds of convenient and the only sensible choices for `'s'.to_i` would be `0`, `nil`, or an exception.

Comment: @muistooshort, I was interested in reading your remarks, as I've been waffling over the pancake issue for quite some time.

Comment: omg that leads to 
"9.1".to_i == 9
"9.1".to_f == 9.1
"9[1".to_f == 9.0
"9,100".to_i == 9

I think I would have preferred nil. why is 0 more convenient than nil?

Answer (score 3):

Invoking `.to_i` on a string will return a number (in base 10) by interpreting valid numbers at the beginning of the string.

`"string".to_i` returns `0` because `.to_i` couldn't interpret a valid number from the start of the string. `"9".to_i` returns `9` because the leading (or in this case, the only) character is "9" and it could be interpreted as a valid number.

This doesn't mean that invoking `.to_i` on a string that starts with a letter will always return `0` though. For example, `"b6".to_i(16)` returns `182` because this means you want to interpret "b6" (in base 16, aka hexadecimal) as base 10.

See the documentation here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i